# Replace a part of URL with every word from a list

Tags: python

I am currently working on a script that will conjugate all verbs into an excel file. I have a list of 3000 verbs from a textfile and for these verbs, I created a textfile including a list of 3000 URLs. For every verb, I need to create its URL.

A sample URL for a verb: "https://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-[INSERT VERB HERE]-werden.html". I want to replace "[INSERT VERB HERE]" with every word from the textfile and create a list of 3000 URL's into a text file.

When I want to figure out how this can be done, my brain hurts actually.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```py
url = "https://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-{}-werden.html"

with open('input.txt') as f_in, open('output.txt', 'w+') as f_out:
    for word in f_in:
        print(url.format(word), file=f_out)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped. But If I look at the code, I don't understand what this code does. Do you mind if you explain?